# regex to extract by be removing a pattern if present at the end

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to extract value from field if containing "- E1/E2" and ignore the rest.

I have used `(?<value>.*)\s+-\s+E[1-3]*` but it doesn't extract if doesn't contain E1/E2.

below sample values. it doesn't work for 2,4 sample data. Unable to understand how do i make E1/E2 as optional.

1. hello - I am here at - E1
2. Kilo
3. How are you - E3
4. Cool
5. simple - E1 - Dev
6. another simple - E2 QA

Comment: Not sure what method you are using, but `^(?<value>.*?)(?:\s+(?:-\s+)?E[1-3].*)?$` might work. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HaWhxq/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much.. i was unable to figure out that myself, although i read that ? makes it optional.

Comment: The `(?:...)?` is an optional non-capturing group, but there are some other things that need to be addressed in your regex. See my answer below for explanation.

Comment: If you need to study regex, at this moment, I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. And keep an eye on SO regex tag, try answering yourself.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there a good guide to explain the regex above basics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use

```js
^(?<value>.*?)(?:\s+(?:-\s+)?E[1-3].*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HaWhxq/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<value>.*?)` -  Group "value": zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s+(?:-\s+)?E[1-3].*)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:-\s+)?` - an optional sequence of `-` and one or more whitespaces
  - `E[1-3]` - `E` and a digit from `1` to `3`
  - `.*`  - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: it worked fine on regex101.com. But when i tried to use in my field extraction in Splunk. It doesn't extract any value.

to debug i removed ? after .*  `(?<value>.*)(?:\s+(?:-\s+)?E[1-3].*)?` it extracts complete word including E2

Comment: i missed to add $ at the end.

Comment: @Praphi Right, the `$` anchor is important as it makes all these optional patterns still match till the string end.